# org.apache.shiro.UnavailableSecurityManagerException

Tags: shiro

I have a big problem on my project. I have looked everywhere in internet but nothing was found. So this is my Bean:

```
@Named(value = "loginBean")
@SessionScoped
public class LoginBean implements Serializable {

@EJB
private RoleServiceLocal rsbl;

@EJB
private ProfilServiceLocal psbl;

@EJB
private UtilisateurServiceLocal usbl;

private String username;
private String password;
private String newPass;
private String retapPass;
private String lastPass;
private String us = "";
private String per = "";
private String question;
private String recupResponse = "";
private String reponse;
private String creerDoleance, modifierDoleance,
        creerficheExec, modifierficheExec, creerRapportTest, modifierRapportTest, fiche, direction, creerDirection, modifierDirection,
        creerProduit, modifierProduit, creerClient, modifierClient, creerVersion, modifierVersion, technicien, creerTechnicien, modifierTechnicien,
        creerMAJ, modifierMAJ, MAJ, doleance, ficheExec, RapportTest, produit, client, version, technique, creerTechnique, modifierTechnique,
        profil, creerProfil, modifierProfil, associerProfil, associerRole, activerCompte, desactiverCompte, securite, administration;
private Utilisateur user;
private Utilisateur utilisateur;
private boolean remember = false;
private boolean admin;

@EJB //HUM Tu m'as vraiment dérangé.plus de 24h avant de me rappeller de te mettre.hum
private ProfilRoleServiceLocal prsbl;


public LoginBean() {
    user = new Utilisateur();
    utilisateur = new Utilisateur();

}

@PostConstruct
public void init() {

    List<Role> all = rsbl.getAll();
    if (all.isEmpty()) {
        this.rsbl.saveOne(new Role(1, "Créer une Doléance", "doleance"));
        this.rsbl.saveOne(new Role(2, "Modifier Doléance", "doleance"));
        this.rsbl.saveOne(new Role(3, "Créer une fiche", "fiche"));
        this.rsbl.saveOne(new Role(4, "Modifier une fiche", "fiche"));
        this.rsbl.saveOne(new Role(5, "Créer une fiche d'exécution", "fiche d'exécution"));
        this.rsbl.saveOne(new Role(6, "Modifier fiche d'exécution", "fiche d'exécution"));
        this.rsbl.saveOne(new Role(7, "Créer une rapport de test", "rapport de test"));
        this.rsbl.saveOne(new Role(8, "Modifier une rapport de test", "rapport de test"));
        this.rsbl.saveOne(new Role(9, "Créer un produit", "produit"));
        this.rsbl.saveOne(new Role(10, "Modifier un produit", "produit"));
        this.rsbl.saveOne(new Role(11, "Créer un client", "client"));
        this.rsbl.saveOne(new Role(12, "Modifier un client", "client"));
        this.rsbl.saveOne(new Role(13, "Créer une direction", "direction"));
        this.rsbl.saveOne(new Role(14, "Modifier une direction", "direction"));
        this.rsbl.saveOne(new Role(15, "Créer une version", "version"));
        this.rsbl.saveOne(new Role(16, "Modifier une version", "version"));
        this.rsbl.saveOne(new Role(17, "Créer une mise à jour", "mise à jour"));
        this.rsbl.saveOne(new Role(18, "Modifier une mise à jour", "mise à jour"));
        this.rsbl.saveOne(new Role(19, "Créer une solution technique", "solution technique"));
        this.rsbl.saveOne(new Role(20, "Modifier une solution technique", "solution technique"));
        this.rsbl.saveOne(new Role(21, "Modifier planning", "planning"));
        this.rsbl.saveOne(new Role(22, "Créer profil", "profil"));
        this.rsbl.saveOne(new Role(23, "Modifier profil", "profil"));
        this.rsbl.saveOne(new Role(24, "Créer securite", "securite"));
        this.rsbl.saveOne(new Role(25, "Associer profil", "role"));
        this.rsbl.saveOne(new Role(26, "Associer role", "role"));
        this.rsbl.saveOne(new Role(27, "Activer compte", "compte"));
        this.rsbl.saveOne(new Role(28, "Désactiver compte", "compte"));
        this.rsbl.saveOne(new Role(29, "Modifier securite", "securite"));
    }

    List<Profil> alle = psbl.getAll();
    if (alle.isEmpty()) {
        this.psbl.saveOne(new Profil(1, "Administrateur", "administrer"));
        this.psbl.saveOne(new Profil(2, "Super Admin", "Super admin"));
        this.psbl.saveOne(new Profil(3, "Directeur", "directeur"));
        this.psbl.saveOne(new Profil(4, "Responsable", "Responsable"));
        this.psbl.saveOne(new Profil(5, "Collaborateur", "collaborer"));
        this.psbl.saveOne(new Profil(6, "Technicien", "technicien"));
    }

    List<Profil> profils = psbl.getBy("nom", "Rohastrick");
    UserTransaction tx = TransactionManager.getUserTransaction();
    if (profils.isEmpty()) {
        try {
            tx.begin();
            this.psbl.saveOne(new Profil(1, "Rohastrick", "rot2rick"));
            List<Role> roles = this.rsbl.getAll();
            for (Role role : roles) {
                ProfilRole pr = new ProfilRole();
                pr.setRole(role);
                pr.setProfil(psbl.getOneBy("nom", "Rohastrick"));
                prsbl.saveOne(pr);
            }

            Utilisateur ut = new Utilisateur();
            ut.setNom("Rot2rick");
            ut.setLogin("Rohastrick");
            ut.setPass(new Sha256Hash("helen@").toHex());
            ut.setEmail("admin");
            ut.setTelephone("admin");
            ut.setProfil(psbl.getOneBy("nom", "Rohastrick"));
            ut.setActif(true);
            usbl.saveOne(ut);
            tx.commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            try {
                tx.rollback();
            } catch (IllegalStateException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(FicheBean.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (SecurityException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(FicheBean.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (SystemException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(FicheBean.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (AuthenticationException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();

            }
        }
    }

}

public boolean checkIntConnection() {
    boolean status = false;
    Socket sock = new Socket();
    InetSocketAddress address = new InetSocketAddress("www.google.com", 80);
    try {
        sock.connect(address, 3000);
        if (sock.isConnected()) {
            status = true;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {

    } finally {
        try {
            sock.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }

    return status;
}

public void login() throws IOException {
    System.out.println("Test Roler");
    try {
        System.out.println("user=" + username);
        System.out.println("ps=" + password);
        user = usbl.getOneBy("login", username);
        if (user != null) {
            if (user.isActif() == false) {
                RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
                context.execute("PF('error').show();");
                username = "";
                return;
            }
        }

        if (user != null) {
            boolean test = new Sha256Hash("admin").toHex().equals(user.getPass());
            if (test && user.isActif() == false) {

                RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
                context.execute("PF('dialogpasse').show();");
                return;
            }

        }

        UsernamePasswordToken token = new UsernamePasswordToken(username.trim(), password.trim());

        token.setRememberMe(false);

        try {
            SecurityUtils.getSubject().login(token);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(""+ e.getMessage());
        }

        Subject subject = EntityRealm.getSubject();
        if (!username.equalsIgnoreCase("admin")) {

            if (subject.hasRole("Créer une fiche") || subject.hasRole("Modifier une fiche")
                    || subject.hasRole("Créer une fiche d'exécution") || subject.hasRole("Modifier une fiche d'exécution")
                    || subject.hasRole("Créer une Doléance") || subject.hasRole("Modifier une Doléance")
                    || subject.hasRole("Créer un rapport de test") || subject.hasRole("Modifier un rapport de test")
                    || subject.hasRole("Créer un produit") || subject.hasRole("Modifier un produit")
                    || subject.hasRole("Créer une version à un produit") || subject.hasRole("Modifier une version du produit")
                    || subject.hasRole("Créer une mise à jour") || subject.hasRole("Modifier une mise à jour")
                    || subject.hasRole("Créer un Client") || subject.hasRole("Modifier Client")
                    || subject.hasRole("Créer un Technicien") || subject.hasRole("Modifier un Technicien")
                    || subject.hasRole("Créer une Solution Technique") || subject.hasRole("Modifier une Solution Technique")
                    || subject.hasRole("Créer une Direction") || subject.hasRole("Modifier une Direction")) {
                this.administration = "true";
            } else {
                this.administration = "false";
            }

            //connexion();
            if (subject.hasRole("Créer une fiche")
                    || subject.hasRole("Modifier fiche") || subject.hasRole("Modifier fiche")
                    || subject.hasRole("Supprimer fiche")) {
                this.fiche = "true";
            } else {
                this.fiche = "false";
            }

            if (subject.hasRole("Créer securite") || subject.hasRole("Modifier securite")
                    || subject.hasRole("Créer profil") || subject.hasRole("Modifier profil")
                    || subject.hasRole("Creer securite") || subject.hasRole("Associer profil")
                    || subject.hasRole("Associer role") || subject.hasRole("Activer compte")
                    || subject.hasRole("Désactiver compte")) {
                this.securite = "true";
            } else {
                this.securite = "false";
            }

            if (subject.hasRole("Créer une Doléance")) {
                this.creerDoleance = "true";
            } else {
                this.creerDoleance = "false";
            }

            if (subject.hasRole("Modifier une Doléance")) {
                this.modifierDoleance = "true";
                this.doleance = "true";
            } else {
                this.modifierDoleance = "false";
                this.doleance = "false";
            }

            if (subject.hasRole("Créer un rapport de test") || subject.hasRole("Modifier un rapport de test")) {
                this.RapportTest = "true";
            } else {
                this.RapportTest = "false";
            }

            if (subject.hasRole("Créer une fiche d'exécution") || subject.hasRole("Modifier une fiche d'exécution")) {
                this.ficheExec = "true";
            } else {
                this.ficheExec = "false";
            }

            if (subject.hasRole("Créer une fiche d'exécution")) {
                this.creerficheExec = "true";
            } else {
                this.creerficheExec = "false";
            }

            if (subject.hasRole("Modifier une fiche d'exécution")) {
                this.modifierficheExec = "true";
            } else {
                this.modifierficheExec = "false";
            }

            if (subject.hasRole("Créer un rapport de test") || subject.hasRole("Modifier un rapport de test")) {
                this.RapportTest = "true";
            } else {
                this.RapportTest = "false";
            }

            if (subject.hasRole("Créer un rapport de test")) {
                this.creerRapportTest = "true";
            } else {
                this.creerRapportTest = "false";
            }

            if (subject.hasRole("Modifier un rapport de test")) {
                this.modifierRapportTest = "true";
            } else {
                this.modifierRapportTest = "false";
            }

            if (subject.hasRole("Créer un produit") || subject.hasRole("Modifier un produit")) {
                this.produit = "true";
            } else {
                this.produit = "false";
            }

            if (subject.hasRole("Créer un produit")) {
                this.creerProduit = "true";
            } else {
                this.creerProduit = "false";
            }

            if (subject.hasRole("Modifier un produit")) {
                this.modifierProduit = "true";
            } else {
                this.modifierProduit = "false";
            }

            if (subject.hasRole("Créer un technicien") || subject.hasRole("Modifier un technicien")) {
                this.technicien = "true";
            } else {
                this.technicien = "false";
            }

            if (subject.hasRole("Créer un technicien")) {
                this.creerTechnicien = "true";
            } else {
                this.creerTechnicien = "false";
            }

            if (subject.hasRole("Modifier un technicien")) {
                this.modifierTechnicien = "true";
            } else {
                this.modifierTechnicien = "false";
            }

            if (subject.hasRole("Créer un client") || subject.hasRole("Modifier un client")) {
                this.client = "true";
            } else {
                this.client = "false";
            }

            if (subject.hasRole("Créer un client")) {
                this.creerClient = "true";
            } else {
                this.creerClient = "false";
            }

            if (subject.hasRole("Modifier un client")) {
                this.modifierClient = "true";
            } else {
                this.modifierClient = "false";
            }

            if (subject.hasRole("Créer un client") || subject.hasRole("Modifier un client")) {
                this.client = "true";
            } else {
                this.client = "false";
            }

            if (subject.hasRole("Créer un client")) {
                this.creerClient = "true";
            } else {
                this.creerClient = "false";
            }

            if (subject.hasRole("Modifier un client")) {
                this.modifierClient = "true";
            } else {
                this.modifierClient = "false";
            }

            if (subject.hasRole("Créer une solution technique") || subject.hasRole("Modifier une solution technique")) {
                this.technique = "true";
            } else {
                this.technique = "false";
            }

            if (subject.hasRole("Créer une solution technique")) {
                this.creerTechnique = "true";
            } else {
                this.creerTechnique = "false";
            }

            if (subject.hasRole("Modifier une solution technique")) {
                this.modifierTechnique = "true";
            } else {
                this.modifierTechnique = "false";
            }

            if (subject.hasRole("Créer une direction") || subject.hasRole("Modifier une direction")) {
                this.direction = "true";
            } else {
                this.direction = "false";
            }

            if (subject.hasRole("Créer une direction")) {
                this.creerDirection = "true";
            } else {
                this.creerDirection = "false";
            }

            if (subject.hasRole("Modifier une direction")) {
                this.modifierDirection = "true";
            } else {
                this.modifierDirection = "false";
            }

            if (subject.hasRole("Créer un produit") || subject.hasRole("Modifier un produit")) {
                this.produit = "true";
            } else {
                this.produit = "false";
            }

            if (subject.hasRole("Créer un produit")) {
                this.creerProduit = "true";
            } else {
                this.creerProduit = "false";
            }

            if (subject.hasRole("Modifier un produit")) {
                this.modifierProduit = "true";
            } else {
                this.modifierProduit = "false";
            }

            if (subject.hasRole("Créer une mise à jour") || subject.hasRole("Modifier une mise à jour")) {
                this.MAJ = "true";
            } else {
                this.MAJ = "false";
            }

            if (subject.hasRole("Créer une mise à jour")) {
                this.creerMAJ = "true";
            } else {
                this.creerMAJ = "false";
            }

            if (subject.hasRole("Modifier une mise à jour")) {
                this.modifierMAJ = "true";
            } else {
                this.modifierMAJ = "false";
            }

            if (subject.hasRole("Créer un client") || subject.hasRole("Modifier un client")) {
                this.client = "true";
            } else {
                this.client = "false";
            }

            if (subject.hasRole("Créer un client")) {
                this.creerClient = "true";
            } else {
                this.creerClient = "false";
            }

            if (subject.hasRole("Modifier un client")) {
                this.modifierClient = "true";
            } else {
                this.modifierClient = "false";
            }

            if (subject.hasRole("Créer un profil") || subject.hasRole("Modifier un profil")) {
                this.profil = "true";
            } else {
                this.profil = "false";
            }

            if (subject.hasRole("Créer un profil")) {
                this.creerProfil = "true";
            } else {
                this.creerProfil = "false";
            }

            if (subject.hasRole("Modifier un profil")) {
                this.modifierProfil = "true";
            } else {
                this.modifierProfil = "false";
            }

            if (subject.hasRole("Associer un profil")) {
                this.associerProfil = "true";
            } else {
                this.associerProfil = "false";
            }

            if (subject.hasRole("Associer role")) {
                this.associerRole = "true";
            } else {
                this.associerRole = "false";
            }

            if (subject.hasRole("Activer un compte")) {
                this.activerCompte = "true";
            } else {
                this.activerCompte = "false";
            }

            if (subject.hasRole("Désactiver un compte")) {
                this.desactiverCompte = "true";
            } else {
                this.desactiverCompte = "false";
            }

        }

        SavedRequest savedRequest = WebUtils.getAndClearSavedRequest(Faces.getRequest());
        Faces.redirect(savedRequest != null ? savedRequest.getRequestUrl() : "index.xhtml");
    } catch (AuthenticationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        FacesMessage mf = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_FATAL,
                "Nom d'utlisateur ou mot de passe incorrect", "");
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage("", mf);
    }
    //return "index";
}

public String currentUser() {
    Utilisateur user = EntityRealm.getUser();
    if (user == null) {
        return "Admin";
    }
    return EntityRealm.getUser().getLogin();
}

public Date sessionTime() {
    return EntityRealm.getSubject().getSession().getStartTimestamp();
}

public void logout() {
    try {
        EntityRealm.getSubject().logout();
        Faces.redirect("login.xhtml");
        username = "";
    } catch (IOException ex) {
    }

}

public void mot() {
    System.out.println("test");
}

public void modifierPasse() {
    System.out.println("test");
    System.out.println(newPass);
    System.out.println(retapPass);
    if (newPass.trim().equals(retapPass.trim())) {
        user.setPass(new Sha256Hash(newPass.trim()).toHex());
        user.setQuestion(question);
        user.setReponse(reponse);
        usbl.updateOne(user);
        question = "";
        reponse = "";
        RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("PF('dialogpasse').hide();");

        FacesMessage mf = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO,
                "Mot de passe corriger", "");
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage("erreur_login", mf);
    } else {
        FacesMessage mf = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_FATAL,
                "Les mots de passe ne concorde pas", "");
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage("erreur_login", mf);
    }
}

public void modifierPasse2() {
    if (new Sha256Hash(lastPass).toHex().equals(EntityRealm.getUser().getPass())) {
        if (newPass.trim().equals(retapPass.trim())) {
            if (new Sha256Hash(newPass).toHex().equals(EntityRealm.getUser().getPass())) {
                FacesMessage mf = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_FATAL,
                        "Tapez un mot de passe différent de l'ancien", "");
                FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage("erreur_login", mf);
                newPass = "";
                lastPass = "";
                retapPass = "";
            } else {
                EntityRealm.getUser().setPass(new Sha256Hash(newPass.trim()).toHex());
                usbl.updateOne(EntityRealm.getUser());
                FacesMessage mf = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO,
                        "Mot de passe corrigé", "");
                FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage("erreur_login", mf);
                RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
                context.execute("PF('dialogpasse').hide()");
            }
        } else {
            FacesMessage mf = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_FATAL,
                    "Les mots de passe ne concorde pas", "");
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage("erreur_login", mf);
            newPass = "";
            lastPass = "";
            retapPass = "";
        }

    } else {
        FacesMessage mf = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_FATAL,
                "mot de passe incorrect!!!", "");
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage("erreur_login", mf);
        newPass = "";
        lastPass = "";
        retapPass = "";
    }
}

public void reinitialiserPasse() {
    Utilisateur u = this.usbl.getOneBy("login", per);
    if (u.isActif() == true) {
        if (reponse.equals(u.getReponse())) {
            u.setPass(new Sha256Hash("admin").toHex());
            u.setQuestion(null);
            u.setReponse(null);
            usbl.updateOne(u);
            question = "";
            reponse = "";
            RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
            context.execute("PF('dialogRecup').hide();");
            FacesMessage mf = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO,
                    "Mot de passe réinitialisé", "");
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage("erreur_login", mf);
        } else {
            FacesMessage mf = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_FATAL,
                    "La reponse est fausse", "");
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage("erreur_login", mf);
        }
    }

}

public String recupererQuestion() {
    if (!per.equals("")) {
        Utilisateur u = this.usbl.getOneBy("login", per);
        String quest = "";
        if (u != null) {
            if (!u.getPass().equals(new Sha256Hash("admin").toHex())) {
                if (u.isActif() == true) {
                    quest = u.getQuestion();
                    RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
                    context.execute("PF('dialogRecup').show();");
                    context.execute("PF('dialogOublie').hide();");
                    return quest;
                } else {
                    per = "";
                    RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
                    context.execute("PF('dialogOublie').hide();");
                    FacesMessage mf = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_FATAL,
                            "Votre compte est inactif,contactez l'administrateur", "");
                    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage("erreur_login", mf);
                }
            } else {
                RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
                context.execute("PF('dialogOublie').hide();");
                FacesMessage mf = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO,
                        "Connectez vous à votre compte pour changer votre mot de passe", "");
                FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage("erreur_login", mf);
            }
        } else {
            per = "";
            FacesMessage mf = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_FATAL,
                    "le login saisi est inconnu", "");
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage("erreur_login", mf);
        }
    }
    return "";
}

this is the JSF page
<h:form id="login" >
        <p:growl id="message" life="4000" showSummary="true" />
        <p:outputPanel autoUpdate="true" style="background-image:">
            <div class="card login-panel ui-fluid" style=" border-radius: 10px;">
                <div class="ui-g">
                    <div class="ui-g-12">
                        <p:graphicImage name="images/logo2x.png" library="ultima-layout" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="ui-g-12">
                        <h:panelGroup styleClass="md-inputfield">
                            <p:inputText id="identifiant" value="#{loginBean.username}" />
                            <label>Email...</label>
                        </h:panelGroup>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ui-g-12">
                        <h:panelGroup styleClass="md-inputfield">
                            <p:password id="motdepasse" value="#{loginBean.password}" />
                            <label>Mot de Passe...</label>
                        </h:panelGroup>    
                    </div>
                    <div class="ui-g-12">
                        <p:commandButton process="@form"  value="Se connecter" icon="ui-icon-person" update="message" actionListener="#{loginBean.login()}" />
                        <p:commandButton value="Mot de passe oublié" icon="ui-icon-help" styleClass="secondary" onclick="PF('dialogOublie').show()"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </p:outputPanel>
    </h:form>
```

and the error

> Caused by: org.apache.shiro.UnavailableSecurityManagerException: No SecurityManager accessible to the calling code, either bound to the org.apache.shiro.util.ThreadContext or as a vm static singleton.  This is an invalid application configuration.

Comment: So i'm not understanding well. that means what will i soppose to aid please Thanks

Comment: See [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for information on asking a question more clearly.